# Shifting Menu Items

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, hover

I am currently using the Porto Theme through Wordpress and I am having an issue with a menu I am working on. I have added some CCS to add a border upon hover of each menu item. However, when hovered each menu item correctly displays the border but shifts up slightly, as well as moves the other menu items as well. I am new to Stack Overflow so I am not sure how to display the HTML from wordpress so I'm not sure how to go about getting help here.

Thanks, K.Zinger

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] so that others can help you with your problem. If you need help inserting code into your question, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). TLDR-- paste a code snippet into your answer, select the text for your code block, and hit the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

Because border modifies the layout, it makes sense that everything would shift if you're only adding a border on hover.

You have some options:

1. You could always have a border, but make it `transparent` when it's not being hovered
2. If the border is a solid border, you could use a box-shadow instead of a border (`box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FF0000`)